# glibc detected runtime error on calls to free()

Tags: glibc, gfortran

I am running a model with moi compiled with gfortran all model compilations are ok but when I run the model I am having the below error.

It is a numerical model I am using on a linux computer 8 processor and strangely is having this error.

```
malloc: using debugging hooks
malloc: using debugging hooks
malloc: using debugging hooks
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000097b65980 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000097b761a0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000008b4b1d00 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000008b4c2520 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000097b55360 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000008b4a16e0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000086abd9c0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000086ace1e0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000096cfb990 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000096d0c1b0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000086aad3a0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000096ceb370 ***
+ '[' 11 -ne 0 ']'
+ exit 8
+ exit 8
:wq
```

Comment: It's quite hard to help with such few informations and context. The message you are getting is pretty much a segfault with some additional infos: it complies about an invalid pointer on a call to `free()`. It might be a double free...

Comment: Below a few lines of the log when running the model.

Comment: 2b9241474000-2b92414b5000 rw-s 00000000 00:92583                      /dev/shm/mpich_shar_tmpjWcITs (deleted)
2b9244000000-2b9244021000 rw-p 2b9244000000 00:00 0 
2b9244021000-2b9248000000 ---p 2b9244021000 00:00 0 
7fff7fedc000-7fff7fef5000 rw-p 7ffffffe5000 00:00 0                      [stack]
7fff7fffd000-7fff80000000 r-xp 7fff7fffd000 00:00 0                      [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
*** glibc detected *** ./rsm.x: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000084ffdf90 ***